# How to create an iterator class in python that will iterate through an input in reverse order?

Tags: python-3.x, class, iterator, iterable

I need to create an iterator class that will iterate through an input in reverse order. Pretty much I need to replicate the following code using class.

```
def reverse(iterable)
    rev = len(iterable) - 1
    while rev >= 0:
        yield iterable[rev]
        rev -=1
```

The code should work something like:

```
>>> nums = [1, 5, 6]
>>> ex = RevIter(nums)
>>> iter(ex) is ex
True
>>> next(ex) == 6
True
>>> next(ex)
5
>>> next(ex)
1
```

My code so far is not working:

```
class RevIter:

    def __init__(self,iterable):        
        self.iterable = iterable
   
    def __next__(self):        
        rev = len(iterable) - 1        
        while rev >=0:            
        yield iterable[rev]            
        rev -= 1
```

NOTE: I can't use any built in functions such as reverse() or iter()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__next__` method in an iterable class is not
a generator itself - it is a plain function that
returns a value, called as part of the iterator
protocol.

It is the `__iter__` special class that can optionally
be a generator and feature  `yield`. But then, if you call
`iter(myinstance)`, with `__iter__` being a generator
function (i.e. a function that has an `yield` keyword),
the `iter` call will create a new iterable instance,that
is distinct from `myinstance`

For the `mysinstance is iter(myinstance)` part to work,
you have to feature an `iter` method that returns `self`.
And a `__next__` method that will return the next desired item.

```
class RevIter:

    def __init__(self,iterable):        
        self.iterable = list(iterable)
        self.index = len(self.iterable)

    def __iter__(self):
        # if you want the instance to be able to reset the iteration,
        # redefine "self.index" here.
        # self.index = len(self.iterable)
        # this is what "iter(instance)" becomes:
        return self
   
    def __next__(self):        
        self.index -= 1
        if self.index < 0:
             raise StopIteration()
        return self.iterable[self.index]
```

Comment: meh - sorry, I ended up doing all the thing. I usually should just give you a hint when there is an exercise to do - but you'd need the information on what the `__iter__` method does anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `yield` in the `__next__` special method, `yield` is reserved for generators.

Here's a hint for an implementation:

```
class RevIter:
    def __init__(self, iterable):        
        self.iterable = iterable
        self.index = len(iterable)
   
    def __next__(self):
        # Maybe update self.index to prepare it for the next element?
        return # Maybe return something using the iterable and the index?
```

To think about how the update should go, imagine that when stepping through a 5-element list the indices would be (in order)

```
4, 3, 2, 1, 0
```